# How to setup custom header related rules in elastic beanstalk loadbalancer

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-cloudformation, amazon-elb

i'm working on an api deployed with aws elastic bean stalk.

As am writing the deployment code (cloudformation) i couldn't find a way to customize the application load balancer created by beanstalk.

I would like to setup a rule linked to a header of the request, it's something you can't even do in the beanstalk config console.

is there a way to update the properties of the load balancer created by beanstalk ?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can. This is addressed here:

- [Modifying the resources that Elastic Beanstalk creates for your environment](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-format-resources-eb.html)

For ALB, you have to modify `AWSEBV2LoadBalancer` resource. This is done by creating/modify [custom resources](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/environment-resources.html) in your `.ebextensions`:

- [Adding and customizing Elastic Beanstalk environment resources](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/environment-resources.html)